# How do I extend a half dynamic formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say I have 3 numbers in A1 B1 and C1, and I want to calculate the values of their division result in D1, and I want it to be written to A2 B2 and C2. I write in A2 the formula:

```
A1/D1
```

And it gives me the right result. But when I extand A2 to B2 and C2, the formule that's being copied to B2 and C2 is:

```
B1/E1
C1/F1
```

When what I want is:

```
B1/D1
C1/D1
```

Meaning, one variable of the formule (the numerator) is changing according to the row and the other variable of the formula (the denominator) is const. how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just lock the denominator by putting `$` sign like this.

```
=A1/$D1
```

This way, when you drag the formula to the right, `D1` reference will not change
since it was locked by `$` sign placed in front.

If you want to lock `D1` when you drag the formula downward, add another `$` sign
behind `D1` like this.

```
=A1/$D$1
```

This will make `D1` reference locked by column and by row.

Similarly, if you just want `D1` locked by row, remove `$` sign in front like this:

```
=A1/D$1
```

Hope this helps.