# Can you use a row as a variable in an equation in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Say you have an equation `=SUM(C32:AC32)/AD53` where **32** is always going to be the row number. I'd like to write this as equation I can just copy it to each cell as is, rather than having to update the row number each time I paste it to a different row. This seems really basic, but I can't figure out from the other answers in Stack Overflow how this would be written, or how to ask the question properly.

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. You may [find your answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472937/how-do-i-extend-a-half-dynamic-formula). I think your problem is properly using the `$` in your formula.

Answer (score 4):

You need to distinguish between copying the cell and copying the content of the cell.

When you edit the formula in the formula bar and copy the formula, you can then paste that same formula into a different cell's formula bar. The formula will not be changed, but pasted verbatim.

A more common approach is to copy the **cell** and paste it onto another cell. If the source cell contains a formula, then the behaviour of the cell references in the formula will depend on their definition.

- An absolute cell reference contains the $ sign in front of the column
  AND the row reference.

  `=$A$1`

  Copied anywhere else, this formula will always reference cell A1.
- A relative cell reference does not contain any $ sign. Both the row
  AND the column will change when the  is copied somewhere else.

  `=A1`

  Copied one row down, the cell reference will change to `=A2` and copied
  one column across it will change to `=B1`. Copying further will increment row and column in the same way.
- A mixed reference can anchor either the column or the row

  `=A$1`

  Copied down, the row reference will not change. Copied across, the
  column reference will.
- and the other mixed reference

  `=$A1`

  Copied down, the row reference will change. Copied across, the column
  reference will not change.

The fastest way to get the correct formula to a range of cells is to determine **first** if you want row and/or column to be absolute or relative. Then write the formula accordingly and copy the **cell** down and across as required.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Put a dollar sign before 32 and this will fix it. You can do the same with the column or you can do both too.